# Build HTML5 offline app with bunch of multimedia content

Tags: html, web-applications

I just wanted to hear opinions.

I know that now it is not really possible to build a native (desktop, tablet) like web app that contains (should work in offline mode with) a bunch of multimedia content (there is no consistent way to store and access multimedia data on the client).

Do you see any steps in this direction or such apps will be a native platform privilege in future as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline storage appcache does more or less what you are asking for. It's actually quite possible, at least in modern browsers. Check it out:

- http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#applicationcache
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Application_Cache#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: Thank you, I've just read that app cache is not for storing big amount of multimedia data.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to offline storage, there are HTML5 File APIs that you can use. I believe Google Chrome lets its form of 'Apps' use the file APIs.

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/